# Tricky ClassCastException in using the Plastic framework for code generation

Tags: java, classloader

**What's it all about**
Hi everyone - I was looking at a presentation called "Have your cake and eat it too: Meta-programming in Java"

The presenter was Howard M. Lewis Ship, (one?) of the authors of Tapestry - and in making that, a subproject called "plastic" was made to leverage ASM to alter the bytecode.

I won't pretend to be an expert, but the end-result should be that I can write code such that annotated classes, methods and fields can be used to generate further java code thus cutting down on boilerplate code.

**My Question**
The code below is a complete example to demonstrate my problem. The test example should modify the EqualsDemo class such that it contains implementations of equals() and hashCode().
When running it I get an error which basically states that I can't cast an object of type 'com.example.plastic.transformed.EqualsDemo' to 'com.example.plastic.transformed.EqualsDemo' (yes, the same class).

The presenter just mentioned that these errors were annoying without alluding to where they stem from - my searching so far indicates that they pertain to different class loaders.
I have, however, been completely unable to fix the problem, hence my question here(!)

```
com.example.plastic.transformed.EqualsDemo cannot be cast to com.example.plastic.transformed.EqualsDemo
        at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:28)
```

So what do I need to do ? Replace class loaders ? (if so, how?) or is there some part of Plastic I don't get ? Some method for generating proxy objects or similar that I need to use for things to go smoothly ?

PS!
The examples I've found so far all use what I *think* is Groovy in the final use of the annotated instances.

Hopefully someone are more competent than I :)

Links:
Tapestry Homepage (plastic is contained as a jar in the download): http://tapestry.apache.org/

### Main.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.tapestry5.internal.plastic.StandardDelegate;
import org.apache.tapestry5.plastic.ClassInstantiator;
import org.apache.tapestry5.plastic.PlasticManager;

import com.example.plastic.transformer.EqualsHashCodeTransformer;
import com.example.plastic.transformed.EqualsDemo;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        List<String> pList = new ArrayList<String>();
        pList.add("com.example.plastic.transformed");

        PlasticManager pm = PlasticManager
                .withContextClassLoader()
                .delegate( new StandardDelegate(new EqualsHashCodeTransformer()) )
                .packages(pList)
                .create();


        final String EQUALSDEMO = "com.example.plastic.transformed.EqualsDemo";
        ClassInstantiator<EqualsDemo> i = pm.getClassInstantiator(EQUALSDEMO);
        i.newInstance().hashCode();
        /*
        com.example.plastic.transformed.EqualsDemo cannot be cast to com.example.plastic.transformed.EqualsDemo
        at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:28)
        */
    }
}
```

### ImplementEqualsHashCode.java

```
package com.example.plastic.annotations;

import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface ImplementEqualsHashCode {

}
```

### EqualsHashCodeTransformer.java

```
package com.example.plastic.transformer;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.tapestry5.plastic.FieldHandle;
import org.apache.tapestry5.plastic.MethodAdvice;
import org.apache.tapestry5.plastic.MethodDescription;
import org.apache.tapestry5.plastic.MethodInvocation;
import org.apache.tapestry5.plastic.PlasticClass;
import org.apache.tapestry5.plastic.PlasticClassTransformer;
import org.apache.tapestry5.plastic.PlasticField;

import com.example.plastic.annotations.*;

public class EqualsHashCodeTransformer implements PlasticClassTransformer {
    private MethodDescription EQUALS = new MethodDescription("boolean", "equals", "java.lang.Object");

    private MethodDescription HASHCODE = new MethodDescription("int", "hashCode");

    private static final int PRIME = 37;

    public void transform(PlasticClass plasticClass){

        //check that the class is annotated
        if(!plasticClass.hasAnnotation(ImplementEqualsHashCode.class)) {
            return;
        }

        List<PlasticField> fields = plasticClass.getAllFields();


        final List<FieldHandle> handles = new ArrayList<FieldHandle>();
        for(PlasticField field : fields){
            handles.add(field.getHandle());
        }

        //HashCode method introduction :)
        plasticClass.introduceMethod(HASHCODE).addAdvice(new MethodAdvice() {
            public void advise(MethodInvocation invocation){
                Object instance = invocation.getInstance();
                int result = 1;

                for(FieldHandle handle : handles){
                    Object fieldValue = handle.get(instance);

                    if(fieldValue != null)
                        result = (result * PRIME) + fieldValue.hashCode();
                }

                invocation.setReturnValue(result);

                //Don't proceed to the empty introduced method
            }

        });

        plasticClass.introduceMethod(EQUALS).addAdvice(new MethodAdvice() {
            public void advise(MethodInvocation invocation) {
                Object thisInstance = invocation.getInstance();
                Object otherInstance = invocation.getParameter(0);

                invocation.setReturnValue(isEqual(thisInstance, otherInstance));

                //Don't proceed to the empty introduced method
            }

            private boolean isEqual(Object thisInstance, Object otherInstance) {

                if(thisInstance == otherInstance)
                    return true;

                if(otherInstance == null)
                    return false;

                if(!(thisInstance.getClass() == otherInstance.getClass())) 
                    return false;

                for(FieldHandle handle : handles){
                    Object thisValue = handle.get(thisInstance);
                    Object otherValue = handle.get(otherInstance);

                    if(!(thisValue == otherValue || thisValue.equals(otherValue)))
                        return false;
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

### EqualsDemo.java

```
package com.example.plastic.transformed;

import com.example.plastic.annotations.ImplementEqualsHashCode;


@ImplementEqualsHashCode
public class EqualsDemo {
    private int intValue;
    private String stringValue;

    public int getIntValue(){
        return intValue;
    }

    public void setIntValue(int intValue){
        this.intValue = intValue;
    }

    public String getStringValue(){
        return stringValue;
    }

    public void setStringValue(String stringValue){
        this.stringValue = stringValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't want to add the packages to the plastic manager -- it uses a different classloader and will load those classes, making two copies of the classes in those packages (one in the parent classloader and one in the plastic classloader) which will give you the ClassCastException you are seeing when the framework tries to cast to your class.  Try this instead:

```
import org.apache.tapestry5.internal.plastic.StandardDelegate;
import org.apache.tapestry5.plastic.ClassInstantiator;
import org.apache.tapestry5.plastic.PlasticManager;

public class MainClass {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      PlasticManager pm = PlasticManager
            .withContextClassLoader()
            .delegate(new StandardDelegate())
            .create();
      ClassInstantiator<EqualsDemo> ci = pm.createClass(EqualsDemo.class, new EqualsHashCodeTransformer());
      System.out.println(ci.newInstance().hashCode());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess instead of

```
PlasticManager.withContextClassLoader()...
```

using the following should fix your problem:

```
PlasticManager.withClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader())...
```

Comment: `.withClassLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader())` will not work, nor will `EqualsDemo.class.getClassLoader()` and `getClass().getClassLoader()` seems not to work as I can't treat getClass as a static method.

Comment: You are right about `getClass()`,  I missed that. But at least `EqualsDemo.class.getClassLoader()` should have worked... Hmm...

Comment: Oh yes, I may have be unclear on that part, `EqualsDemo.class.getClassLoader()` works, but still results in the same ClassCastException.